# How to copy Stream until you find a certain Element using the streamAPI?

Tags: java, lambda, collections

i have a list of strings {"a","b","c","d",...}. i want to reduce them up to a certain element. for example this listto elements up to "c". this means that I want to keep all the elements that come before it. is there a way with only using streams to achieve it?

i tried .filter() but that didnt work out

Comment: Please, share your **attempt** and specify the problem you've encountered. Every question on StackOverflow is expected to demonstrate an effort. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)

Comment: Related question: [How is takeWhile different from filter?](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiNuafq3438AhVpxosKHTTwC7gQFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F46850689%2Fhow-is-takewhile-different-from-filter&usg=AOvVaw3aSl28LWyM1fTE6B4zTBIU)

Answer (score 3):

You looking for takeWhile() method

```
String[] chars = {"a","b","c","d","e"};

List<String> justUntilC = Arrays.stream(chars)
        .takeWhile(c -> !c.equals("c"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```